# Understanding jQuery Attribute Selector which uses #

Tags: javascript, jquery

Could someone tell me what below jQuery selector will grab (I didn't write it but I need to understand it)...

```
var $cat = $('a[href="#cat"]');
```

Is it all the anchor tags which have 'cat' in the value of their href attribute?

Also does using the '$' in the variable name have any significance or effect? Is it bad practice?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: It uses the same selection mechanism as css does.

Comment: $cat is just a naming convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will grab something like:

```
<a href="#cat">This link</a>
```

but not the following:

```
<a href="cat">This one</a>
<a href="#dog">This one</a>
<a href="#cattywompus">Another</a>
```

The `[]` in a selector are to select elements with a certain attribute.
There are similar selectors, for example, you can use for "starts with" (`[href^="#cat"]`) or "contains" (`[href*="#cat"]`), but with just the `=` it means equal to.

See more detail here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/

Using $ in the element name is common to indicate that it is a jQuery object or a DOM node, as opposed to another simpler variable (like an integer or array, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

It gets the anchor element with the given anchor value (in this case, this is the `cat` page anchor).

And no, using `$` in the variable name is not bad practice, it shows at once, that it is a jQuery object. Of course if you are also using AngularJS, it is a more gray are, as it uses the same naming convention for its internal objects.

By "not bad practice" I meant, not bad practice *per se*. So it can be used, but make sure that you use it consistently, because inconstent naming conventions *are* bad practice.

Comment: Is there any advantage of using the $ on a variable?

Comment: Sure, it is very short.

Answer (score 1):

It will return all elements that look something like

```
<a href="#cat" ...>...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It will select an A tag which links points to cat, like

```
<a href="#cat" >Link</a>
```

$var is a valid practice,is standard js you can say

```
var $myvar = "hello";
and
var myvar = "hello";
both will work the same
```

check this link

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1778-using-variable-in-jquery-code-is-just-hungarian-notation.htm

Answer (score 0):

`$('a[href="#cat"]');` will select any Anchor with a href of '#cat'.

Additionally, $ at the start of a variable name is simply a *naming convention*. It doesn't serve a specific meaning, but is often used to identify a variable as a [JQuery Object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).